Clarifications to VNAV PTH and SPD INTV during descent and approach
Concerning FMC Update 14.0+, also called “common VNAV”
Scenario: During descent through 8,000 ft, while being radar vectored in the approach, the typical autopilot Flight Mode Annunciators (FMAs) would display: FMC SPD | HDG SEL | VNAV PTH. The next waypoint in the LEGS page has a speed set at 235B and the following waypoint after that is at 10nm with 3000A/180B - though of course you are actually on radar vectoring, the lateral path is just for guidance.
Suppose an unexpected tailwind occurs, and you decide to start the deceleration early by pressing the SPD INTV button and setting a new speed of 210 kts (approximately up speed plus 5-10 kts).

Clarification 1: When SPD INTV is used to adjust the speed, will the autothrottle (A/T) mode remain in FMC SPD?
The FCOM defines MCP SPD as “the autothrottle maintains the speed set in the MCP IAS/MACH display.” However, MCP SPD does not appear as an option within VNAV, hence why FMC SPD is still the correct mode.
Clarification 2: Will the aircraft begin to decelerate towards the new target speed set by SPD INTV, as displayed in the MCP speed window?
The FCOM states that FMC SPD mode means “the autothrottle maintains the speed commanded by the FMC. The autothrottle is limited to the N1 value shown on the thrust mode display.” If SPD INTV is used, does it set a new target speed in the FMC, effectively “overwriting” the target speed in the CDU? Or does the FMC ignore the MCP IAS/MACH value and continue to use the former CDU target speed speed for its calculations?
Clarification 3: As an alternative to using SPD INTV, could selecting and executing the next waypoint in the LEGS page provide the FMC with updated wind information and assist in recalculating the descent point?
Or could a combination if selecting and executing as well as opening the SPD INTV window be an effective solution?
Clarification 4: When refreshing the LEGS page near a deceleration point, is it possible for the deceleration point to completely disappear? (I believe I have observed this on numerous occasions)
